# На каком бесплатном хостинге можно захостить сокет на python?

Tags: python, сокет, ip, хостинг

Я делаю консольный чат на python. Он уже готов, но мне надо найти бесплатный хостинг для него. Проблема заключается в том, что клиенту нужно знать к какому адресу подключаться. Но вот только, как я узнаю на каком ip-адресе запущен мой сервер?
Иными словами, вот строки в клиенте, с помощью которых, он подключается к серверу:

```
server = 'ip', 9090 #Я не знаю какой ip указывать :(
sock.sendto('CONNECT'.encode('utf-8'), server)
```

Comment: Тоже вот думаю... Ну можно `sock.bind('0.0.0.0', 8080)`, а в клиенте свой ip ...

Comment: `curl ipinfo.io/ip`

Comment: Правда он каждый раз разный (каждый ребут)

Comment: что мешает использовать dyndns?

Comment: @strawdog не могли бы Вы, пожалуйста, рассказать как этим пользоваться?

Comment: введите в поиске google dyndns и сами все узнаете.

Comment: Но как я понял, для того, чтобы использовать dyndns нужен белый ip-адрес, а у меня он серый.

Comment: У Вас - скорее всего. У хостинга вряд ли.

Comment: можно купить хост за $1.5 в месяц